# How to get the closest element by finding innerhtml value using angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Am struggling to find the parent element by using value.

Here i have stored the whole html nodes in one variable.

```
$scope.mail_html = "<asd>My best friend is Mickey.</asd>Who is your favourite:<das class="sdfsdfsdf">Goofy</das>";
```

And my need is to find the closest element of the inner HTML value "Goofy";

The output should be `<das class="sdfsdfsdf">;`

Can anyone please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`angular.element`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) to put the html into a temporary div outside the dom and iterating through all the elements there.

Not really sure what objective is once found

```js
var mail_html = '<asd><span>My best friend is Mickey.</span></asd>Who is your favourite:<das class="sdfsdfsdf">Goofy</das>';

var $div = angular.element('<div>').append(mail_html),
  els = $div[0].querySelectorAll('*'),
  term = 'Goofy',
  target;
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  if (els[i].textContent.indexOf(term) > -1) {
    target = els[i]
  }
}
if (target) {  
  console.log( target)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```